# How do I join lines in Sketch?

Tags: vector, sketch-app

I don't understand why these two lines won't join:

[image]

Join is disabled:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think the reason why it doesn't work is because I converted one of the paths to outlines. Since this can't be undone, I will redo it manually.